# How can I run my Java program from different directory

Tags: java, java-8

I am new at Java. I have installed my JDK on `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`. When I am in the `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_131` this directory and execute my java program, it is ok. It runs. But when I am in the different directory it does not run.This error appears `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

May be I added env variables to path not correctly?
How can I solve it?

Comment: I think you need to configure your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.  After this, `javac` (and `java`) should be accessible everywhere.

Comment: You need to set PATH variable for diff directory . go to your enviroment variable and set path their

Comment: how can I do this? firstly I define a varible called JAVA_HOME that holds the address to java?

Comment: To *run* a Java program, you should not need `javac`, as that’s the tool for *compiling* a program, which you don’t need to repeat for every execution. It is not surprising that it can’t be found without a proper path setup, however, it’s surprising that, whatever you do, is working when your current working directory is `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`, as `javac` is not directly contained in that directory. It seems, you didn’t post the entire context. Besides that, I’m going to remove the `java-7` and `jdk1.6` tags, as you didn’t specify to have any Java installation of these versions…

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your java path. Please refer this link [java.com](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.
Include your JDK path up to and including /bin in the environment path properties in system environment which will be in control panel.

Comment: Best is in fact to set a JAVA_HOME environment variable and use $JAVA_HOME/bin in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @jwenting: it seems, a lot of Java developers are overestimating the relevance of the `JAVA_HOME` variable. Java itself doesn’t use that variable. I never set that variable in the last twenty years…

Comment: @Holger It's mostly a convenience thing, allowing you to keep the $PATH definition short. And some tools do use it, things like app servers and some build tools for example in order to find the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Java bin path to the system environment variable so that the system could recognize the java command from other directory as well.

> go to -> My Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced System Settings

Click on the bottom right part of the new opened dialog box: Environment Variables

Add `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin` in the path of the system variables.

Restart the system after saving the changes.